How can I travel to the US to attend hackathons as a CS undergraduate?
I am an Indian citizen and passport holder. However, I study at the University of Calgary in Canada. I want to attend hackathons in the US, but as an Indian citizen I don't know which visa application to file and what documents are required to get permission from the US government to come to their country and attend these hackathons.

Probably a B1/B2 visa? Tourism/Business

Problem is the nearest US consulate shows the interview date that is available after 875 days for B1/B2 Visa

That is a problem, but not what you're asking about

Participate in virtual hackathons and you won’t need a visa at all.

@RishabhAgarwal apply for the B visa.  You may well want one three years from now.  Keep checking the appointments at every consulate in Canada that you can reasonably reach -- the wait times change fairly often as they add capacity.  Consider applying in India during a visit, if you plan to visit.

Note that while most US consulates in Canada have wait times in the 700-900 days range, Vancouver is "only" 455 days. Or you could take a vacation to Bridgetown, Barbados (66 days) or Kingston, Jamaica (32 days), neither of which require a visa for Indian citizens. There are posts where delays are even shorter, but I believe you would need a visa to get there, though I haven't cross-referenced all of them between https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_requirements_for_Indian_citizens and https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/visa-information-resources/global-visa-wait-times.html

Would you be attending these events as an individual, or associated with the University of Calgary?  Because if it's the latter, what do they say?

@jcaron the Department of State notes that the times reported in their system apply to "residents" (of the country where the consulate is located, I suppose, but if not then of the consular district).  Nonresidents are advised to check the post's site for additional information.  For example, the US consulate in Belmopan (Belize) reports a wait time of 25 calendar days, but on their site they say "Please note that wait times for non-residents of Belize may be longer than for residents. The wait time for an appointment for a non-resident in all visa categories is currently about three months."

@jcaron many countries that require visas of Indian citizens waive that requirement for those with Canadian visas or residence permits or make a visa on arrival available, or, if not, getting a visa may be relatively quick.  So if Rishabh Agarwal wants to try applying in another country in the Americas, there are many more options than just those countries that allow visa-free entry for Indians by default.

@phoog I am gonna do that

@PeterM I'll be attending individually.

@phoog I didnt quite get what you meant by : "many countries that require visas of Indian citizens waive that requirement for those with Canadian visas or residence permits or make a visa on arrival available, or, if not, getting a visa may be relatively quick. So if Rishabh Agarwal wants to try applying in another country in the Americas, there are many more options than just those countries that allow visa-free entry for Indians by default"?

@RishabhAgarwal to get to (for example) Mexico or Belize, you would normally need a visa because you are an Indian citizen.  However, because of your Canadian visa, you can go to Mexico without a visa and you can obtain s visa on arrival for Belize.  Even if there is a country that doesn't have such preferential treatment, you can probably get a visa in a few weeks at most.
